# How to fix draw rectangle from Right to Left

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

When draw a rectangle Going to the right side

[Right Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EErm1.png)

and when I draw rectangle going to the left side it becomes like this

[Left Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTZdt.png)

Here is my Code:

```
ObservableCollection<RectItem> RectItems = new ObservableCollection<RectItem>();

public void MouseDownEvent(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
 startPoint = Mouse.GetPosition((IInputElement)sender);
}

public void MouseMoveEvent(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

  if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Released) return;if (selected) return;if (_isDragging) return;var pos = Mouse.GetPosition((IInputElement)sender);

        // Set the position of rectangle
        var x = Math.Min(pos.X, startPoint.X);
        var y = Math.Min(pos.Y, startPoint.Y);

        // Set the dimenssion of the rectangle
        var w = Math.Max(pos.X, startPoint.X) - x;
        var h = Math.Max(pos.Y, startPoint.Y) - y;


        if (RectItems.Count != 0)
        {
            var exist = RectItems.Where(xx => xx.X == x).LastOrDefault();
            if (exist != null)
            {

                exist.Height = h;
                exist.Width = w;
            }
            else
            {
                RectItems.Add(new RectItem
                {
                    X = x,
                    Y = y,
                    Height = h,
                    Width = w,
                    id = RectItems.Count() + 1,
                });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            RectItems.Add(new RectItem
            {
                X = x,
                Y = y,
                Height = h,
                Width = w,
                id = RectItems.Count() + 1,
            });
         }
```

}
        public void PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            StopDragging();
            e.Handled = true;
        }

Comment: How can I fix my rectangle draw. Because when I draw and drag it to the left side it becomes what is shown on the Left Image.

Comment: You only ever *add* rectangles to the `ObservableCollection` but never remove them.

Comment: But the purpose of my add is for my 2nd or more rectangle (But in new Position). If I remove them I can only make 1 rectangle.

Comment: So you mean the problem is that they change in size as you drag them?

Comment: No, Sorry it's my first time asking here and I'm just a newbie programmer. My problem is when dragging the rectangle to the left side the result is from the 2nd picture but when i drag(draw) a rectangle going to the right side the result is from the 1st picture I want my Rectangle when draw on the left side the result  should be like on the 1st picture. Your suggestion removing on my ObservableCollection is satisfying my need but I can only draw 1 rectangle.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page! - Also: `Canvas` is hardly a helpful tag and: Do fix the formatting! - Finally: We see no drawing code, so how can we know what you actually do??

Comment: @TaW I am targeting WPF on this code. And the drawing code is being handled at my ObservableCollection. Sorry for my bad question and expressing my code. This is just my first time I just tried asking question because I cant find a solution to this problem.